# python zlib how to decompress many objects

Tags: python, zlib

I tried to write many zlib block on my file, is there a way I can get all uncompressed content from my file? from the example code below I can only get my first data. Thank you in advance for any input!

```py
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 29 2018, 19:04:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zlib
>>> str1 = b'my first string'
>>> str2 = b'my second string'
>>> z1 = zlib.compress(str1)
>>> z2 = zlib.compress(str2)
>>> with open('test.z', 'wb') as fh:
...     fh.write(z1)
...     fh.write(z2)
... 
23
24
>>> p = open('test.z','rb').read()
>>> p
b'x\x9c\xcb\xadTH\xcb,*.Q(.)\xca\xccK\x07\x00.6\x05\xe6x\x9c\xcb\xadT(NM\xce\xcfKQ(.)\xca\xccK\x07\x003\xfb\x06:'
>>> zlib.decompress(p)
b'my first string'
>>> zlib.decompress(p)
b'my first string'
```

Comment: I _suspect_ that the zlib can tell from its header how many bytes to read and decompress.  Since the file contains two separately compressed bytestrings, the first header tells it to read 23 bytes and so the remainder never get read.  See what happens if you decompress `p[23:]`, or if you concatenate the lines before compression `z = zlib.compress(str1+str2)`

Comment: Thank you @snakecharmerb. `zlib.decompress(p[23:])` does work and gives me the content of `str2`, I am making an assumption that I didn't know the sizes/offsets in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to decompress concatenated compressed streams in a single function or method call<sup>*</sup>.  However, it's possible to get equivalent functionality using the tools in the [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) package.

```
>>> import zlib
>>> b1 = b'Here is some data'
>>> b2 = b'Here is some more data'
>>> stream = zlib.compress(b1) + zlib.compress(b2)


>>> while stream:
...     dco = zlib.decompressobj()
...     dec = dco.decompress(stream)
...     print(dec)
...     stream = dco.unused_data
... 
b'Here is some data'
b'Here is some more data'
```

[zlib.decompressobj()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompressobj) creates an object which decompresses a single compressed stream - like `zlib.decompress` - and exposes the remaining bytes in the stream in its [unused_data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.Decompress.unused_data) attribute.  So we can decompress in a loop until the entire concatenated stream has been decompressed.

<sup>*</sup>*At least, not that I could find*

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you!!